# Auto update db schema with existing Android app

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, forceclose

I have published an earlier version of my app on Play Store which had no db. Now I made a lot of changes as  per the requirements and added several tables in my app.

I just want to confirm when I push this new app on Play Store, do all my existing users will easily open the app or they will get FC as there is no db exists in their app?

Please suggest me what will happen and what should I do to not let my users facing FC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As in your previous app you have not set database, so just initialize your database on your first screen like in splash screen. 
  So as soon as user will start application first database will be created and then app will start so there will not be any kind of issue or app crash scenario user will face.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class derived from [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), which automatically manages creating or updating the database when needed.

Also see [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21881992/11654) (which is *not* your problem).